# How to set SELinux to Permissive

Tags: twrp, selinux

Since installing XtreStoLite 3.1.1, SELinux is set to Enforcing (when I try to boot into TWRP recovery). I tried setting it to permissive (Enforcing = 0) using a terminal emulator (the phone is rooted), but to no effect. It would appear that this is preventing me from booting to TWRP to install Aroma.

Any ideas?

(FYI, SELinux Mode Changer didn't work)

Answer (score 3):

If SELinux Mode Changer doesn't work, and you are properly rooted, then your kernel likely isn't compiled with permissive mode and was compiled with the flag `EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DCONFIG_ALWAYS_ENFORCE=true` which doesn't allow permissive mode to be set in anyway.

You will need to get the kernel source from the manufacturer, which **should** be available if they are honoring the GPL license, and in the file `~/android/kernel/security/selinux/Makefile`

Find the line of code that says:

`EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DCONFIG_ALWAYS_ENFORCE=true`

and change the value of it to `false` and recompile the kernel and make a zImage and flash it to boot.

- Example [Source](http://graemehill.ca/compiling-permissive-android-kernel/) for reference

That being said, TWRP should support SELinux Enforce, just never **EVER** run a `fix permissions`

Comment: It actually turns out that I had to flash a different version of TWRP and then I was able to boot to it. It was on an obscure website that I never would have found by myself, but someone on xda-developers pointed me to it. Apparently, it doesn't even matter that SELinux is is set to Enforcing, as that isn't causing any ill effects now. Thanks for you help, though.